# Run-time error '1004' due to INetCache\Content.MSO

Tags: excel, vba

I have a VBA script in Excel which worked fine so far. There was no change in the file/macro however I received the following error in the middle of the run:

"Run-time error '1004':
Sorry, we couldn't find

C:\Users\'UserID'\Appdata\Local\Microsoft\Windows\INetCache\Content.M
Is it possible it was removed, renamed or deleted"

(note, only Content.M is shown in the error, probably it is MSO folder)

The only change I have in the environment is the OFFICE 365 since it has been automatically updated.

This folder did not exist at all (and macro worked earlier) however I tried to create this folder structure. It did not work, furthermore I received additional error pop ups.

I have also tried the basic trick with disabling/enabling macro security settings but did not help.

Office cannot be repaired (company admin setup does not allow).

Any help would be appreciated.